# Is a Node.js module a singleton?

Tags: javascript, node.js, modular

I used to implement singleton this way:

```
class MySomething {
    constructor(props) {}
}

let myInstance = null;
module.exports = (props) => {
    //first time call
    if(props) {
        myInstance = new MySomething (props);
    return myInstance;
} else {
return myInstance;
}
```

this assumes that at app.js (entry file) I will call first:

```
require('./MySomething')(props)
```

then everywhere in the project I use:

```
const instanceOfSomething = require('./MySomething')();
```

I discovered that every time I got a new instance!

What's wrong in my code?

I tried also this way:

```
class MySomething {...}

const mySomething = (function() {
  
    let myInstance = null;

    return {
    
        init: function() {
            myInstance = new MySomething();
        }, 

        getInstance: function() {
            return myInstance ;
        }
    }   
 
})();

module.exports = mySomething;
```

and I got the some problem when importing this module from different files, anyone can explain to me?

every require of file create new instance of mySomething

**UPDATE**

I tried this example now:

```
class MySomething {...}

const mySomething =  {
        myInstance: null,
        init: function() {
            myInstance = new MySomething();
        }, 
        getInstance: function() {
            return myInstance ;
        }
    }   

};

module.exports = mySomething;
```

The same problem happened, maybe it is related to my project structure, I will explain it here:

the code below belongs to module "facts"

facts folder contains a folder named "dao" this folder contains MySomething.js (the singleton)
in the facts/index.js I have:

```
  const Localstorage = require('./dao/MySomething');
    
    exports.init = (path) => {
       Localstorage.init(path)
     
    }
    exports.Localstorage = Localstorage;
```

Now in a folder named "core" which contains the "facts" folder I re-exported the Localstorage again in "index.js" like this:

```
 const facstModule = require('./facts');
    
    exports.Localstorage = facstModule.Localstorage;
```

Then in "schedule" folder which contains "Runtime.js" within I write:

```
const { Localstorage } = require('../core');


setTimeout(() => {
const localstorageIns = Localstorage.getInstance(); //this is always null!
}, 5000)
```

In app.js file (entry point) I did:

```
const facts =  require('./src/facts');
facts.init(__dirname);
```

Normally instance will be created before the timeout execute the callaback,
But I noticed that there two instance of Localstorage which is singleton

Answer (score 0):

Every require of file create new instance of mySomething because every time you return new object with `init` method and `getInstance` method.

If you need singleton you need do like this:

```
class MySomething {
    constructor() {
        if (!MySomething.instance) {
            MySomething.instance = this;
        }
    }

    getInstance: function() {
        return MySomething.instance;
    }
}

module.exports = MySomething;
```

Comment: doesn't solve the problem: everytime require make 'myInstance = undefined'

Comment: Because you export function which return every time new object. But you need to import object or class which every time return same object

Answer (score 0):

the cleanest way to do a singleton is

```
class MyClass () { ... }

module.exports = new MyClass()
```

if you need a singleton that gets instantiated once, I would do:

```
class MyClass () { ... }

let myClass
const MyClassSingleton = (...args) => {
  if (myClass) {
    return myClass
  }
  myClass = new MyClass(...args)
  return myClass
}

module.exports = MyClassSingleton
```

Comment: this is what I used to do, and technically the some code I wrote

Answer (score 0):

```
class Singleton {
    constructor() {
        this.my_obj;
    }

    static makeObject() {
        if (!this.my_obj) {
            this.my_obj = new Singleton();
        }
        return this.my_obj;
    }
    add() {
        return 1
    }
}


// so to get the object we need to call the makeobject method

const obj = Singleton.makeObject()

console.log(obj.add());
```

Comment: @maroodb you don't check if you've already have an instance before creating a new one.